# Subset Implication Questions

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A,B,C$ be three sets. Prove that $A \setminus B \subseteq C \Rightarrow A \setminus C \subseteq B.$

A couple of points I want some clarification on:

1. Do I assume this implication to be true?
2. Is "If $A \setminus B \subseteq C$" my assumption and I'm trying to conclude that "$A \setminus C \subseteq B$"?
3. If #2 is correct, does that mean I have to work solely off my assumption?

Now off to my work:

$A \setminus B \subseteq C$

Let $x \in A \setminus B$, then $x \in A \land x \notin B$. Then $x \notin A \cap B$ and since $A \cap B \subseteq A \cup B, x \notin A \cup B$. But, I don't know how this will help my reach the conclusion of the "then" statement.

Thank You.

Comment: As of now, the formatting in your question is ugly. Add dollar signs ($) around your math symbols and use the commands \cap and \cup for intersection and union of sets respectively. For more information, check out: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: And by the way, if $x \in A \setminus B$, then $x \in A \cup B$, contrary to the conclusion in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you assume that $A \setminus B \subseteq C$.  Here's a proof.

Assume $x \in A \setminus C$.  Then $x \in A$ but $x \notin C$.  We want to prove $x \in B$.

Suppose that were false, so that $x \notin B$.  We know from above that $x \in A$, so putting both halves together we find that $x \in A \land x \notin B$, so $x \in A \setminus B$.  But our assumption is that $A \setminus B \subseteq C$, so $x \in A \setminus B \Rightarrow x \in C$.  This contradicts the statement above that $x \notin C$, so our assumption that $x \notin B$ must be false.  This contradiction proves that $x \in B$ and we are done.

Answer (score 0):

The main thing here is not to confuse (1) the antecedent of the conditional that is to be proved with (2) the antecedent of this antecedent , in case this antecedent is itself a conditional statement.

[image]